# Re-order data in a dataframe with divided information (reshape in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am working on a dataset of this type (example dataframe):

```
V1<-c("-","-","*","-","-","*","*")
V2<-c("01","01","01","02","02","02","02")
IND<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
sex<-c(1,2,1,1,2,2,2)
rang<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4)

df<-data.frame(V1,V2,IND,sex,rang)
```

I used the reshape command

```
df1<-reshape(df,idvar = "V2",v.names = c("V1","IND","sex"),
          timevar = "rang",direction="wide")
```

I get this result:

```
> df1
  V2 V1.1 IND.1 sex.1 V1.2 IND.2 sex.2 V1.3 IND.3 sex.3 V1.4 IND.4 sex.4
1 01    -     a     1    -     b     2    *     c     1 <NA>  <NA>    NA
4 02    -     d     1    -     e     2    *     f     2    *     g     2
```

Which is close to the desired result.

However I would like to know if there is a way to return indvidus higher than 3 to the row, keeping the same individuals from columns 1 and 2, to get a result like this :

```
  V2 V1.1 IND.1 sex.1 V1.2 IND.2 sex.2 V1.3 IND.3 sex.3 
1 01    -     a     1    -     b     2    *     c     1
4 02    -     d     1    -     e     2    *     f     2 
5 02    -     d     1    -     e     2    *     g     2
```

Or should I take my table manually?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Sincerely

Theo DA SILVA

Comment: what do you mean by return to the row?

Comment: your input data looks already quite tidy. What is your final goal? Perhaps it is better to think about the way to reach it.

Comment: I work on pedigree data, and my final goal is to have by row each individual with his two parents.
The idea is to have each childrens of a family in separate rows and not on the same row